# While Creating a new project

Tags: android, eclipse

I updated my SDK and my Eclipse Juno IDE.

While I'm creating a new android project I follow these steps,

images:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Now, when I click on "Finish", the "Create Project" window doesn't get closed. Though the Project is still created but lots of errors.

[image]

Why it always tries to extend "ActionBarActivity" instead of "Activity", even I selected "API 8" as the minimum SDK?

Why there are errors? How to fix those?

Comment: Why do you use urls for image ??? Can you be specific what errors you are getting ??

Comment: You should select "Black Activity" when you create project to prevent using ActionBar from template

Comment: I'm new here, so I have no permission to post images, yet.. All the errors and the steps are shown in the images. Yes, I select blank Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the wizard dialog you show in your first image set everything to be API 8 (min SDK, target SDK and Compile with options) and set Theme to None.

In the dialog you show in your second image uncheck the "Create activity" checkbox.

That's it. You'll get a blank project although you'll have to add your own `Activity` class (right-click the /src directory then New and add class and derive it from android.app.Activity) and you'll also have to create your own XML layout file.

Comment: Thanks..
unchecking "Create Activity" solves the problem even if the "target" and "compile with" are set to "API 19".
But it's annoying that, even though I'm using an advanced IDE like eclipse, I'll have to create a new activity class, layout, and add that to manifest xml every time I create a new project.

Comment: @deb_rider : Yes it is annoying. It's a recent change to the ADT which is causing this. There have been complaints made about it so hopefully the ADT developers will fix it for the next release of the ADT - it's causing problems for a number of people.

Answer (score 0):

`ActionBarActivity` is class from comparability library, and if you want to use action bar in app for API less then 11 you need to use it. [Add comparability library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) to your project.

Comment: But I don't want to use action bar.. I don't find any option to deselect the action bar while creating the project.

Comment: Then extends Activity, and set Min API to 11.

Comment: Did you see the images in my post?

Comment: Yes, and you see this text? SET MIN API TO 11 NOT TO 8.

Comment: Tried... But Doesn't work. Same issue.. Looks like I have to disable creating activity at the time of creating project, and create it manually afterwards... Thanks Anyway..

Comment: @Divers : Not everyone wants a min SDK version of 11 - my phone (for example) runs Froyo. Basically the ADT devs messed things up thinking it was a good idea at the time but it's not and it's causing a lot of confusion particularly for new Android developers (the basic projects assume using a `Fragment` for example). One of the worst things devs can do is 'assume' everybody wants something and imposing it on them. The sooner the ADT devs provide a truly "blank" project which just uses an `Activity` and doesn't impose an `ActionBar` and support libraries the better.